# Python find the declared variable type

Tags: python, thrift

I facing issue while making a thrift call due to None value sent for int.

So in the code I am planning to check the declared type. I am planning to write something like the below (Since we have too many object dont want to code for each field)

```
def(thrift_obj):
    for field in thrift_obj.__dict__:
        #Here I want to check the declared type of the field (not the type of value of the field)
        # if the type is int and value is None then assign it as zero
```

I have tried using the type function using `type(getattr(thrift_obj, field))` it gives the type of the value inside the field.(Consider a structure carry an field i of type i32 and it carry None type and if I check the type it responds me NoneType. )
I like to check the declared type of the field.

Comment: What's a "declared type"? Python is dynamically typed and `None` happens to have the type `NoneType`.

Comment: @L3viathan I assume he means the Thrift variable type, as declared in the .thrift file

Comment: Thats right. The fields declared in the structure of thrift file.

Comment: What's not clear to me: Why do you want to check the type at all? The type is known beforehand (from the IDL) and does not change. And Thrift does not support variant types. So why check it again?

Comment: I am writing a common method to set the values from the DB select (using SQLAlchemy) to thrift object. If the name matches then I set the fields. If there is no value in the table then I get None value. When I send the None to the thrift service, it throws me a exception that I cant set None type to integer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe?

```
import types
def(thrift_obj):
  for field in thrift_obj.__dict__:
    if isinstance(thrift_obj.__dict__[field],(int,types.NoneType)):
      thrift_obj.__dict__[field] = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But that did not help. Still see  <type 'NoneType'> when I try print(type(thrift_obj.__dict__[field]))

Comment: As someone else said above (L3viathan), variables in python are not declared.  It is called "dynamic typing" (you can search for this).  That's why you can only get the type of what's in a variable.

Comment: Thanks Let me check on dynamic typing. There could be fields of type string. If string then I need to set empty string.